# How to get sub attribute value in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, minidom

I have an xml file like this.

```
<approved-by approved="yes">
<person>
<name>XXX/name><signature>XXXXX</signature>
<location>XX</location><company>XXX</company><department>XX</department>
</person>
</approved-by>
<revision-history suppress="yes">
<rev-info>
<rev>PA1</rev>
<date><y>2013</y><m>01</m><d>22</d></date>
```

I need to retrieve values of 'rev' from all xmls and the value of approved. I want whtr the doc is approved or not. I have a script like this.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
import os
import sys
def shahul(dir):   
  for r,d,f in os.walk(dir):
     for files in f:
        if files.endswith(".xml"):
            dom=parse(os.path.join(r, files))
            name = dom.getElementsByTagName('rev')
            title = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')
            approved=dom.getAttribute('approved')
            print (files, title[0].firstChild.nodeValue,name[0].firstChild.nodeValue, approved, sep='\t')
shahul("location")
```

I am able to get the value under 'rev' but i am not able to get value of the attribute 'approved-by'. I understand my syntax is not right to get the value of approved, but i dont know it.

i need the following as output.

FILE_NAME, Title, PA1, yes

Please guide me.

Comment: Your XML file appears to have some syntax problems: `<revision-history>` for example is never closed.

Comment: I just copied a part of the XML file Thom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have only one `approved-by` tag in the XML:

Change:

```
approved = dom.getAttribute('approved')
```

To:

```
approved_by = dom.getElementsByTagName('approved-by')
approved = approved_by[0].attributes['approved'].value
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt say this before. I tried this step before and got the following error.

AttributeError: 'NodeList; object has no attribute 'getAttribute'

Comment: @Shahul Hameed: Sorry, I used "selenium syntax" instead of "minidom syntax"; answer revised...

Comment: Thanks for your help brother. I got the same error again. It seems that we dont have a syntax like (.attributes) in minidom. May be it is there. We are using it wrongly "(

Comment: Now it says, AttributeError" 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'attributes'.

Comment: @Shahul Hameed: Sorry, again, I used "selenium syntax" instead of "minidom syntax" (this time `getElementByTagName` instead of `getElementsByTagName`). Please try it now (worked for me).